# How can I separate my Matlab object's code into different files?

Tags: oop, matlab

I'm writing a Matlab object oriented program and the program is now getting to over 1000 lines. I want to move parts of the script to other `.m` files for easier maintenance.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [class folder](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brqy4ox-1.html), then place each of the [methods](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brdqinq.html#brdqipw-1) for the class in a separate file in this folder (instead of in one large file).

Answer (score 2):

No question, it is as well a matter of taste whether you put *methods* in a *class folder* or *one class file*. Regarding clarity I opt for the *one class file* approach.

Classes growing that large, might be a target for refactoring.  Smaller classes are easier to maintain, document and test.